# Carregando os valores de um select na minha GridView

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, webforms, sql-select

Meu DAL que faz o **Select** e salva no tipo list<>

```
 using System;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using MySql.Data;
 using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
 using Geax1.Model;

 namespace Geax1.DAL
{
public class ListaVeiculosDAL
{
    private static List<_Veiculos> lv = new List<_Veiculos>();
    public static void ListaVeiulos(_Clientes obj)
    {
        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;Database=xpto;User ID=root;Password='';"))
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tab_veiculo ORDER BY id;", conn);

                DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(dataset);

                foreach (DataRow linha in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    _Veiculos veiculo = new _Veiculos();

                    veiculo.Modelo1 = Convert.ToString(linha["modelo"]);
                    veiculo.Placa1 = Convert.ToString(linha["placa"]);
                    veiculo.Quilometragem1 = Convert.ToString(linha["quilometragem"]);
                    veiculo.Cor1 = Convert.ToString(linha["cor"]);
                    veiculo.Chassi1 = Convert.ToString(linha["chassi"]);
                    veiculo.Quilometragem1 = Convert.ToString(linha["tipo"]);

                    lv.Add(veiculo);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<_Veiculos> retornaVeiculo()
    {
        return lv;
    }
  }
}
```

Chamando meu método dentro da minha **GridView**. Porém, ao executar a página fica em branco, não retorna nenhum valor do **select**.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Geax1.DAL;
using Geax1.Model;

namespace Geax1.Views
{
 public partial class ListagemVeiculos : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         GrdVeiculo.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
         GrdVeiculo.DataSource = ListaVeiculosDAL.retornaVeiculo();
         GrdVeiculo.DataBind();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A propósito, esse teu tratamento de exceção aí não faz muito sentido :-) Você está capturando uma exceção para simplesmente relançá-la. Para este efeito você pode simplesmente não ter o tratamento de exceção (eliminar o `try..catch`).

Comment: Faça o teu DAL retornar o próprio DataSet que foi preenchido pelo DataAdapter (`adapter.Fill(dataset)`) e ligue o datasource do grid diretamente ao DataSet: `GrdVeiculo.DataSource = dataset`. Ou isto ou você precisará implementar sua lista de veículos do modo que ela seja uma fonte de dados válida.

Comment: Essa forma não funcionou.
GrdVeiculo.DataSource = dataset

Comment: Agora é depurar. Por exemplo, dataset tem dados?

Comment: Tem como você entrar no chat? Te explico melhor por lá.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou ativar o `AutoGenerateColumns`, provavelmente.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GrdVeiculo.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    GrdVeiculo.DataSource = ListaVeiculosDAL.retornaVeiculo();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O método `ExecuteNonQuery` é geralmente utilizado quando você quer manipular os dados no banco, por exemplo para executar um UPDATE quando você só precisa saber o número de linhas afetadas.

Em vez de usar o `MySqlCommand`, utilize `MySqlDataAdapter` para ler as linhas retornadas por um SELECT.

Exemplo:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connection);
MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM...", conn);

DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(dataset);
```

Você agora pode percorrer as linhas em `dataset.Tables[0].Rows()` e criar objetos para preencher uma lista (`List<SeuObjeto>`).

Exemplo:

```
List<Veiculo> veiculos = new List<Veiculo>();

foreach (DataRow linha in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    Veiculo veiculo = new Veiculo();

    veiculo.Placa = linha["PLACA"];
    veiculo.Marca = linha["MARCA"];
    veiculo.Ano = linha["ANO"];

    veiculos.Add(veiculo);
}
```

Veja: [MySqlDataAdapter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqldataadapter.html).

E uma documentação mais completa sobre o `DataAdapter` do ADO.NET: [Populating a DataSet from a DataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bh8kx08z(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: O que seria esse DataSet?

Comment: É um objeto bastante complexo, mas basicamente ele contém uma coleção de `DataTable`, cada um contendo uma coleção de linhas, sendo cada linha é um registro retornado pela sua query.

Comment: Deve estar faltando um "using" para o namespace `System.Data`.

Comment: Sim, chequei aqui e era isso.

Comment: Só não estou conseguindo adicionar o valores que vem do select ao meu List<>. To tendo essa dificuldade porque está meu primeiro contato com o asp.net e C#. Diferente o PHP, que dava um select, execultava a query e dava um echo nos ROW.

Comment: @PauloViníciusMatos Coloquei um exemplo para adicionar os veículos à lista. Se ainda não resolver, atualize sua pergunta com o código que você já tem até agora e o problema encontrado.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17411/discussion-between-paulo-vinicius-matos-and-caffe).

Answer (score 0):

Veja o exemplo do meu código

```
    public Entities.Usuarios[] ListaUsuarios()
    {
        List<Entities.Usuarios> lstUsuarios = new List<Entities.Usuarios>();

        Data.Connection connection = new Data.Connection(this.ConnectionString);
        connection.AbrirConexao();

        StringBuilder sqlString = new StringBuilder();
        sqlString.AppendLine("select * from usuarios");

        IDataReader reader = connection.RetornaDados(sqlString.ToString());

        int idxId = reader.GetOrdinal("ID_USUARIO");
        int idxNome = reader.GetOrdinal("NOME_USUARIO");
        int idxEmail = reader.GetOrdinal("EMAIL_USUARIO");
        int idxLogin = reader.GetOrdinal("LOGIN_USUARIO");
        int idxSenha = reader.GetOrdinal("SENHA_USUARIO");
        int idxAtivo = reader.GetOrdinal("ATIVO_USUARIO");

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Entities.Usuarios _Usuario = new Entities.Usuarios();
            _Usuario.Id = reader.GetInt32(idxId);
            _Usuario.Nome = reader.GetString(idxNome);
            _Usuario.Email = reader.GetString(idxEmail);
            _Usuario.Login = reader.GetString(idxLogin);
            _Usuario.Senha = reader.GetString(idxSenha);
            _Usuario.Ativo = reader.GetInt32(idxAtivo) == 1;

            lstUsuarios.Add(_Usuario);
        }

        connection.FechaConexao();

        return lstUsuarios.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Paulo, já vi o problema do seu código.
Inclua:

`GrdVeiculo.DataBind()`

Logo após a chamada do trecho

`GrdVeiculo.DataSource = ListaVeiculosDAL.retornaVeiculo();`

O resultado será esse

```
GrdVeiculo.DataSource = ListaVeiculosDAL.retornaVeiculo();
GrdVeiculo.DataBind();
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Oi, Raphael, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. A intenção do site é colecionar soluções, não links. O ideal é você colocar aqui um resumo do seus artigos com um "ler mais" no final. Normalmente também é bom ser cuidadoso com a promoção do próprio site, na [help] tem mais informações.

Comment: Raphael, cheguei a utilizar o "DataBind();" Mas continua sem funcionar.

Comment: Já entendi o problema do seu código. Seu `retornaVeiculos()` esta retornando sua lista vazia. Em que comento você invoca o método `ListaVeiulos` ?